# How to render form on button clic in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two registration forms ona a page, but I only want to render one by clicking on proper button: 'Contract Form' or 'Company Form'. Should I do it with v-if? In the code below I just copied few lines of the form.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="contract">UMOWA</button>
    <button @click="company">FIRMA</button>
    <div v-if="contract">
      <form method="post" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <label for="firstname">IMIĘ</label>
        <input id="firstname" v-model="firstName" type="text" required />
        <label for="lastname">NAZWISKO</label>
        <input id="lastname" v-model="lastName" type="text" required />

        <button type="submit">Zarejestruj się</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div v-if="company">
      <form method="post" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <label for="firstname">IMIĘ</label>
        <input id="firstname" v-model="firstName" type="text" required />
        <label for="lastname">NAZWISKO</label>
        <button type="submit">Zarejestruj się</button>
        <input id="lastname" v-model="lastName" type="text" required />
        <label for="email">ADRES E-MAIL</label>
        <input id="email" v-model="email" type="text" required />
        <button type="submit">Zarejestruj się</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you will need to add true in the buttons onclick:

```html
<button @click="contract = true">UMOWA</button>
<button @click="company = true">FIRMA</button>
```